# foo function is called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am cloning a div tag when user click on available div. After cloning it I am inserting it after clicked div tag. This new div tag also has cross link to delete it. However when I click on cross link it does delete that particular div. It means it is working. Now I also have one function named `foo`. This method is called upon adding and deleting div tag. But when I click on delete link, this foo function is called twice. I know its reason because I am attaching click event to both parent of delete link and to delete link itself therefore, it is called twice. But **How can I make it call once upon both adding and deleting div element?**

Here my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C5X23/)

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="bx"></div>    
</div>
```

Here is js

```
$('body').on('click', '.bx', function (e) {
        var clone = $(this).clone();
        clone.append('<a class="bx-del" href="#">X</a>');
        $(this).after(clone);
        foo();
});



$('body').on('click', '.bx-del', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().remove();
        foo();
});

function foo() {
    console.log('foo');
}
```

Comment: Events bubble, when you place an element inside `.bx` both event listeners are triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original answer was :

Assuming `.bx-del`is inside `.bx`(better to add html as well in the question) then adding `e.stopPropagation()` to the `.bx-del`callback should work.

E.g.

```
$('body').on('click', '.bx-del', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    foo();
});
```

[Documention here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

It has been pointed out that both events are actually attached to the body and run as delegated events.  This solution seems to work but the question is whether or not it is reliable.  The question here is in what order are delegated events run?  Are they always run "depth first" or based on the order they were added or what?  Running them depth first would be the most logical in my view, but performance considerations will play a large role here too.

I have been unable to find any hard documentation on this.  The [jQuery .on() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) says

> jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where
>   the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and
>   runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the
>   selector.

which *could* be interpreted as saying that, but could also be an explation of the concept of delegation.

Thus a safer solution to the the original problem, in my view, would be to combine the two lick events into one:

```
$('body').on('click', '.bx', function (e) {
    var t = $(e.target);
    if( t.hasClass('bx-del') || t.closest('.bx-del').length > 0){
        e.preventDefault();
        t.closest('.bx').remove();
        foo();
    } else {
        var clone = $(this).clone();
        if( $('.bx-del', clone).length == 0 ){
            clone.append('<a class="bx-del" href="#">X</a>');
        }
        $(this).after(clone);
        foo();
    }
});
```

(I have also fixed so that cloning a div with a delete button doesn't add a second delete button).

Comment: First off, this has nothing to do with whether `.bx-del` is inside `.bx`.  Both of these event handlers are attached to the `body` object, not to the actual `.bx` and `.bx-del` objects.  I think you're getting lucky that this works. This is taken directly from the jQuery documentation for stopPropagation(): "Note that this will not prevent other handlers on the same element from running.". It does not seem like a generally good practice.

Answer (score 1):

<s>This is what `event.stopPropagation()` is for ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation)). It prevents the event from bubbling up into the DOM tree. If you add `e.stopPropagation()` to your delete link click handler, it will not bubble up to the div that contains it and trigger the click handler there too:</s>

As pointed out in the comments, this is not correct, even though it appears to work correctly. Both event handlers are attached to body, and only via a 'trick' run on specific elements. The event is already at the body element, and will therefore not bubble any further. Furthermore, `event.stopPropagation()` should not stop other handlers from execution, event though they seem to do that right now anyway. The correct function to use here is [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopImmediatePropagation) ([docs at jquery](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/)).

```
$('body').on('click', '.bx-del', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $(this).parent().remove();
        foo();
});
```

Comment: You can't stopPropagation when the event has already propagated up to the `body`.  You can only stop it from propagating even further up the DOM tree.

Comment: Hrmmm; you are correct about not propagating any further. It will however stop any other click handlers on the same element from executing, and since they were in the correct order, this approach -does- work.

Comment: I think you're getting lucky that's all.  This is taken directly from the jQuery documentation for `stopPropagation()`: "Note that this will not prevent other handlers on the same element from running.".  It does not seem like a generally good practice.

Comment: Hrmmm; yes, correct again. `.stopImmediatePropagation()` seems the way to go. I've adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Because you cannot stopPropagation to the `<body>` tag when the event has already propagated to the `<body>` tag and both your events are on the `<body>` tag, I would suggest just attaching the delete event handler right to the delete X object and not use propagation for that event handler.  You can then stopPropagation of that click so it won't be seen by the parent at all.  In your case this is fairly easy.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7CDNG/

```
$('body').on('click', '.bx', function (e) {
        var clone = $(this).clone();
        clone.append('<a class="bx-del" href="#">X</a>');
        $(this).after(clone);
        clone.find('.bx-del').on('click', function(e) {
            $(this).parent().remove();
            foo();
            // stop propagation and prevent default
            return false;
        })
        foo();
    });

function foo() {
    console.log('foo');
}
```

Alternatively, you could put the `.bx` handler on the `document` object and the `.bx-del` handler on the `body` object and then you could stopPropagation up to the `document` object from the `.bx-del` handler.  But, it seems in this case, it is much cleaner to just attach the delete event directly to the delete object and not use delegated event handling to avoid any possible misinterpretation of the `click` event.

Apparently the other answers are getting away with using `.stopPropagation()` on one `body` event handler to stop the other one from firing.  Here's a quote from the jQuery documentation for `.stopPropagation()`: "I think you're getting lucky that's all. This is taken directly from the jQuery documentation for stopPropagation(): "Note that this will not prevent other handlers on the same element from running."  Since both of these event handlers are on the `body` object, it does not seem like a wise and safe move to use `.stopPropagation()` from one to stop the other from running.  It's my opinion that that technique is not safe and is not the conceptually correct way of solving this problem.